# AS3 object inexplicably disappears after 1.5 - 2 minutes

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to as3 but have been learning as I go.
I am creating a container which appears with text field inputs so the user can create a 'post'. This is triggered to occur when an animation is removed from the stage which it does automatically when it has completed.

However after about 1.5-2 minutes the container inexplicably disappears. This is a problem as a user may well want to take more than 2 minutes to make a post.
I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening, could it possible be a garbage collection issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you,

Dan

```
var titleText:Title = new Title();
var titleInput:TextField = new TextField();

var categoryText:Category = new Category();
var categoryInput:TextField = new TextField();

var postText:Text = new Text();
var postInput:TextField = new TextField();

//setup text formats to be used
var postCreationTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

postCreationTextFormat.font = "arial";
postCreationTextFormat.size = 20;
postCreationTextFormat.align = "left";
postCreationTextFormat.leftMargin = 2;


//Fade In Post Creation Box after Seed to Bud Animation.
seedToBud.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, createPostInput);

//Some variables to declare for the createPostInput function.
var postCreationContainer:PostCreationContainer = new PostCreationContainer;
var contentWindow:ContentWindow = new ContentWindow;
var postCreationInputBoxes:PostCreationInputBoxes = new PostCreationInputBoxes;
var thumb:Thumb = new Thumb;
var track:Track = new Track;
var scrollDownArrow:ScrollDownArrow = new ScrollDownArrow;
var scrollUpArrow:ScrollUpArrow = new ScrollUpArrow;

function createPostInput(event:Event)
{
    addChild(postCreationContainer);    
    postCreationContainer.x = 230;
    postCreationContainer.y = 400;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(track);
    track.x = 428;
    track.y = 25;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(thumb);
    thumb.x = 418;
    thumb.y = 25;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(scrollDownArrow);
    scrollDownArrow.x = 418;
    scrollDownArrow.y = 269;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(scrollUpArrow);
    scrollUpArrow.x = 418;
    scrollUpArrow.y = 6;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(contentWindow);
    contentWindow.x = 6;
    contentWindow.y = 6;

    postCreationContainer.addChild(postCreationInputBoxes);
    postCreationInputBoxes.x = 6;
    postCreationInputBoxes.y = 6;

    postCreationContainer.alpha = 0;
    postCreationContainer.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeInCreatePostInput);

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(titleText);
    titleText.x = 0;
    titleText.y = 0;

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(titleInput);

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(categoryText);
    categoryText.x = 0;
    categoryText.y = 60;

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(categoryInput);

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(postText);
    postText.x = 0;
    postText.y = 124;

    postCreationInputBoxes.addChild(postInput); 

    titleInput.defaultTextFormat = postCreationTextFormat;
    titleInput.type = "input";
    titleInput.multiline = false;
    titleInput.wordWrap = false;
    titleInput.maxChars = 150;
    titleInput.border = true;
    titleInput.width = 403;
    titleInput.height = 30;
    titleInput.x = 0;
    titleInput.y = 32;
    titleInput.background = true;
    titleInput.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

    categoryInput.defaultTextFormat = postCreationTextFormat;
    categoryInput.type = "input";
    categoryInput.multiline = false;
    categoryInput.wordWrap = false;
    categoryInput.maxChars = 150;
    categoryInput.border = true;
    categoryInput.width = 403;
    categoryInput.height = 30;
    categoryInput.x = 0;
    categoryInput.y = 96;
    categoryInput.background = true;
    categoryInput.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

    postInput.defaultTextFormat = postCreationTextFormat;
    postInput.type = "input";
    postInput.multiline = true;
    postInput.wordWrap = true;
    postInput.maxChars = 500;
    postInput.border = true;
    postInput.width = 403;
    postInput.height = 361.5;
    postInput.x = 0;
    postInput.y = 156;
    postInput.background = true;
    postInput.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

    stage.focus = titleInput;
    seedToBud.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, createPostInput);
}

function fadeInCreatePostInput(event:Event):void
{
    postCreationContainer.alpha += 0.05;
    if (postCreationContainer.alpha == 1)
    {
        postCreationContainer.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeInCreatePostInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you create multiple posts at the same time with this function? I see your point about garbage collection, but it shouldnt remove stage elements and since you have the variable declared it should be enough to protect it from garbage...

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for a fact that there are no rounding issues with your alpha incrementer?  I'd be checking the integer value of alpha and not the real, floating point value.  Or, do a fuzz comparison (alpha >= 1-FUZZ && alpha <= 1+FUZZ) for some small value of FUZZ.

Comment: The alpha is increasing, so that shouldn't be his problem even if the condition is not triggering. Regardless, this is a good thing to keep in mind in general.